# Why does the solution of an NP problem have to be polynomial size?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I've read in "Introduction to Algorithms" (CLRS) that formal language $L$ is NP-language if and only if there is a polynomial verification algorithm $A(x, y)$ and a constant $c$ such that $$L=\{x\in\{0,1\}\mid \exists y \text{ with } |y| \leq |x|^c\text{ and } A(x, y)=1 \}\,.$$

What is the purpose of the constraint: $|y| \leq(|x|^c)$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, let's refresh the proof that the definition given is indeed equivalent to the standard definition of **NP**, i.e., the class of languages accepted by polynomial-time nondeterministic Turing machines.

Suppose $L$ is accepted by a polynomial-time Turing machine $M$. There is some $c$ such that $M$ runs in time $|x|^c$ for all inputs $x$. The verification algorithm is as follows: given $x$ and $y$, interpret $y$ as being a sequence of states of $M$ (expressed in some appropriate alphabet), and accept the pair $(x,y)$ if, and only if, $y$ describes an accepting path of $M$ on input $x$. Now, for any string $x\in L$, $M$ has an accepting path of length at most $|x|^c$, there exists a $y$, also of length at most $|x|^c$, such that $A$ accepts $(x,y)$. If $M$ rejects $x$, then there is no accepting path, so no string $y$ can describe an accepting path, so $A$ rejects $(x,y)$ for any string $y$.

Conversely, suppose that a polynomial-time algorithm $A$ exists with the properties stated in the question. We can construct a nondeterministic polynomial-time algorithm for $L$ as follows.  Given input $x$, nondeterministitically "guess" (generate) a string $y$ of length at most $|x|^c$ and see if $A$ accepts $(x,y)$. If $x\in L$, then there is a string $y$ of length at most $|x|^c$ such that $A$ accepts $(x,y)$, so our machine accepts; if $x\notin L$, then no string $y$ has the desired property, so our machine rejects. This is a nondeterministic polynomial time algorithm because it does a polynomial about of guessing and a polynomial amount of simulation of $A$.

So, what goes wrong with this if we remove the condition that there exists some $y$ specifically with length at most $|x|^c$?  Well, the first half of the proof still works: if $L$ is in **NP** then $A$ exists and, hey, it still happens to have the property that $|y|\leq |x^c|$, even though that wasn't required. However, the other half of the proof breaks. We no longer have the guarantee that it's enough to guess $|x|^c$ bits. In fact, we have no guarantee at all. We'd have to keep guessing longer and longer strings to test with $A$ and, actually, the procedure would never terminate for $x\notin L$: there's no way to tell if there really is no $y$ for which $A$ accepts $(x,y)$ or if there is such a $y$ but it's just so long that you've not seen it yet (undecidability of the halting problem).

So, without the polynomial bound on $|y|$, every **NP** langauge can still be expressed in this way but, unfortunately, so can all recursively enumerable languages. The polynomial bound is required to restrict the class of languages described to just **NP**.